# XML Authentification and request data

Tags: php, ajax, xml, api, xmlhttprequest

I never worked before with XML and unfortunately I couldnt find so far the right solution through google.

In my application which will be hosted under domain https://domain-a.de I need to request datas from a third party application https://domain-b.de. For this purpose they provided me a xml api.

I have a form which looks as followed

```html
<input type="text" class="consumption" name="energy-consumption">
<button onclick="getOffer()">Create Offer</buttone>
```

as soon as the button is clicked I want to request from an xml sheet informations.
I dont want to do it with php cause then I would need to reload the page and that wouldnt make sense in my cause thats why I want to use ajax for requesting the data from the xml api.

To get the informations I need to create a identity check request as soon as the applications starts.

```html
<Request>
  <Identity>
    <userid>DE001</userid>
    <password>123456789ok</password>
   <Identity>
  </Request>
```

After the authentifikation process the server will respond an authentficationcode which will be necessary for further requests.

For example:

```html
<Request>
  <Identity>
    <AuthCode>Response Code from Server after successful authentifikation through Username and Pass</AuthCode>
   </Identity>
   <quotation>
    <zip>10179</zip>
    <consumptionP>4000</consumptionP>
   </quotation>
  </Request>
  
  Response From the Server would be than 
  <Response>
    <data>
      <provider gvnr="1">Provider A</provider>
      <provider gvnr="2">Provider B</provider>
     </data>
    <Response>
```

This data will be displayed than through inner.HTML in my application and the user is able to choose it.

Could anybody in here tell me how to connect to this xml file and retrieve the data through this authentifikation?

In general is my app build in javascript and php for the requests to xml i want to use then ajax as well never worked before with it but shouldnt be a problem I guess cause im able to write in js.

Thanks in advance for ur help guys

Comment: To avoid PHP the second domain must be CORS enabled, which is not a thing you can influence. Besides that, you can use PHP and not reload the page ... using AJAX.